# File upload not working in phonegap's webview android - inappbrowser

Tags: jquery-mobile, file-upload, webview, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I am using phonegap webview for displaying my mobile website in android.

In which file upload is not working.

```
<input type="file">
```

Is there any phonegap plugin or any other way to implement file upload in phonegap webview.

Comment: I am going through the same issue. How did you solved the problem?

Comment: Here's an easy fix for this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42375766/1457709

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload a file from a Phonegap application you need to implement a File-transfer plugin. The following link will help you with your problem. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue on https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-seems-to-clobber-ability-to-upload-files-via-forms. Just add

```
data-ajax="false"
```

to the form attributes.